# Finding the average of values, under the condition a column index appears more than once (mySQL))

Tags: mysql, average

I am building a horse racing database and would like to find if any tracks are faster/slower than others. I don't want to just compare the average racing times from each track because some tracks contain a higher ratio of less experienced and slower horses. To avoid this error I want to compare each track with one another using only horses that have raced at both tracks.

So far I have table that contains

location, horse, avg time

I would like to create a view that in the first column contains a single entry for every location. Then I would like every location to have its own column, which would contain the difference of the average times of only horses that have raced at both of the locations

for example I would like the output to look something like this:

╔═══════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║.......location........ ║ .....fleming.... ║ ....morphet.... ║ .......caulfield...... ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║ .......fleming........║.......... 0...........║........-0.1........║...........-0.2...........║
║ .......morphet.......║.........0.1.........║...........0..........║............0.3...........║
║ .......caulfield...... ║..........0.2........║.........-0.3........║.............0 ............║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════════╝

SO far what I have is

SELECT location, 
(CASE `h_adv`.`location`
            WHEN 'fleming' THEN `h_adv`.`AVG_TIME`
        END)) AS `fleming`,
(CASE `h_adv`.`location`
            WHEN 'morphet' THEN `h_adv`.`AVG_TIME`
        END)) AS `morphet`,
(CASE `h_adv`.`location`
            WHEN 'caulfield' THEN `h_adv`.`AVG_TIME`
        END)) AS `caulfield`,

But I have no idea how specify that I want to only use the times of the horses that have raced on both tracks, and that I want to find the difference between these averages. Any help would be appreciated. Sorry about that formatting. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more "SQL" way of doing this is to put the data in rows rather than columns.  Assuming that no horse has raced at a track more than once:

```
select a1.location, a2.location, count(*) as num, avg(time)
from h_adv a1 join
     h_adv a2
     on a1.horse = a2.horse 
group by a1.location, a2.location;
```

If horses have raced at a given track more than once, then you need to pre-aggregate the data by horse and track.  Otherwise, you'll get a little cartesian product and that will cause the averages to be off:

```
select a1.location, a2.location, count(*) as num, sum(sumtime) / count(*) as avg
from (select location, horse, count(*) as numraces, sum(time) as sumtime
      from h_adv
      group by location, horse
     ) a1 join
     (select location, horse, count(*) as numraces, sum(time) as sumtime
      from h_adv
      group by location, horse
     ) a2
     on a1.horse = a2.horse 
group by a1.location, a2.location;
```

SQL tends to be bad at things like aggregating time.  You might be best off if you store the times as a number, such as the number of seconds.

Comment: ahh okay I'm making some progress now. Yeah There's only a single entry per location and horse because I have already found the averages for each. The time is also already stored as number of seconds using a double value. Thanks for your help.